# get diff between 2 columns in postgresql by sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have posgresql and 2 columns with `datetime` values. How can i get difference between this columns by sqlalchemy?
Ideally, i need only one row with max difference value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have already defined the classes and other code required to  create a session for the database, you can query for the maximum difference like this:

```
# code to set up database engine...

class SomeTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'some_table'
    id_ = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    datetime_1 = Column(DateTime)
    datetime_2 = Column(DateTime)

# code to set up session...

>>> from sqlalchemy.sql import func
>>> q = session.query(func.max(SomeTable.datetime_1 - SomeTable.datetime_2))
>>> print(q)
SELECT max(some_table.datetime_1 - some_table.datetime_2) AS max_1 
FROM some_table
>>> print(q.one())
(datetime.timedelta(133, 28552, 844875),)
>>> diff = q.scalar()    # to get the value directly
>>> diff
datetime.timedelta(133, 28552, 844875)
>>> print(diff)
133 days, 7:55:52.844875
```